# The menu on a page is not loading in it's mobile version

Tags: wordpress, web, wordpress-theming, elementor

I am developing a web page with wordpress but I have a problem with the nav menu of the mobile version it is not loading the things it has to load[how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roD1W.jpg)[How it has to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiVTd.jpg)[Wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWnhx.png)

I tried custom CSS, deactivate mega menu, create a template in the mega menu editor

Comment: make sure your WordPress theme has settings for configuring the mobile menu. Look for an option to enable or configure the mobile menu in the theme settings or the WordPress Customizer. You might need to specify which menu should be displayed on mobile devices.
Deactivating the Mega Menu is a good step as it might conflict with the mobile menu. However, if you rely on it for your desktop menu, make sure you have a suitable replacement for the mobile menu.